# Is there a way to spread a texture across each stone and not the whole thing?

Tags: texturing

I have a well model and I'm wanting to spread the texture across each little stone individually and not the whole well at once. Is there a way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way I ended up doing this was to select all the edges and then marking a seam on all of them. But then, the texture will be blurred so you have to turn the scale up on the mapping node.